# How to change status if the bug is solve which is assigned by the administrator in MantisBT?

Tags: tools, defect-tracking, mantis

I am login as the administrator in the MantisBT I have assign developer bug. But if how will developer change the status of the bug which is assign by the tester or admin in MantisBT.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In picture there is 'Edit', 'Assign To' and 'Change Status To:' button on bottom left.

Select the developer or tester from  'Assign To' drop down list and 'Change Status To:' Reopen/Closed/Review/ etc.

Comment: as per your answer i have change that but tester have again set as the resolve i have fix it again now i want to set status as the fix then as per the screen shot hoe can i set that?

Comment: Developer mark status as Resolve and Tester mark as Retest pass/Reopen/closed. Ask tester to mark the appropriate comment. If the above answer works for you please accept the answer.